# Is there a name for a compiler that runs once at runtime right before a program is executed?

Tags: compilers

I wrote a tiny compiler that is used to execute user-defined plugin code. The compiler is shipped as part of the application. When the user loads a plugin, the compiler runs first (once) and then the emitted code is executed.

I'm trying to describe this project in a blog post, and I'm unsure if calling this a "Just in Time" compiler (JIT) is accurate or not. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) indicates that a JIT typically uses runtime information to inform how/when the program gets compiled, and my project does not do anything that fancy.

Is there a common name for a compiler that executes at runtime but does not analyze the execution of the program?

Comment: An idea answer would include a name I can use to describe the fact the my compiler is expected to run on the user's machine rather than the developer's but that it doesn't execute at the same time as the emitted code.

Comment: This seems somehow reminiscent of cpython’s bytecode interpreter system, though different (and I’m not really familiar with the details). I *think* what they do is compile python code to a bytecode (.pyc) just before execution (and only when needed), and then the actual interpreter just uses the bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it's not a JIT, it is just an ordinary compiler.  There's no special name needed -- it's a compiler.

In this context "run time" means when the program being compiled is in the middle of executing.

Comment: Do you think it would be accurate to call it an "ahead of time compiler"? It does run before the code is executed, but I worry that reader would incorrectly infer that the compiler runs on the developer's machine rather than the user's.

Comment: @JordanEldredge consider the alternatives: translation *after* execution reads absurd. *During* (interleaved/concurrent with) execution relates to JIT. *Before* execution seems to suggest itself and has been first, "historically". No need to qualify: *compile-time compiler*?

Comment: @JordanEldredge I have seen "ahead of time compiler" used before, but I can't remember where.